# pandas DataFrame convert codes or labels to categorical

Tags: python, pandas, categories, categorical-data

I'd like to convert a series of a dataframe to categorical, given an existing code/label mapping of the categorical data. I am struggling with the conversion of a series that contains (a) labels to categorical and one that contains the (b) codes to categorical.

The series data contains codes (instead of the category labels which is different to many examples found).

Here's what I got so far:

```
# this is the code-label mapping that I'd like to apply for the
# (a) label -> cat conversion (`df1`)
# (b) code -> cat conversion (`df2`)

>>> cat = pd.Categorical.from_codes([-1, 1, 2, 3], ['-', 'a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> cat.codes
array([-1,  1,  2,  3], dtype=int8)
>>> cat
[NaN, a, b, c]
Categories (4, object): [-, a, b, c]
>>> cat.__array__
<bound method Categorical.__array__ of [NaN, a, b, c]
Categories (4, object): [-, a, b, c]>


>>> df1
   x
0  a
1  a
2  c
3  b
4  b
>>> df2
   y
0  nan
1  1
2  3
3  2
4  2
```

How would I go about converting `x` to be using `cat` as type. I think the problem I have is that I don't quite understand what `pd.Categorical` actually is or how it is meant to be used (is it a dtype (doesn't seem so), is it the actual series (doesn't seem so either, as then it would allow duplicates))? It seems to only hold the actual code-label mapping, but I'm unsure how to make use of it (i.e. apply it to an already existing series).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you may convert `df1.x` to categories of `cat` by use `.astype` on its `dtype` attribute

```
df1.x.astype(cat.dtype)

Out[950]:
0    a
1    a
2    c
3    b
4    b
Name: x, dtype: category
Categories (4, object): [-, a, b, c]
```

Comment: Nice, exactly what I needed (why isn't `pd.Categorical` a dtype to begin with?). How about the reverse conversion (codes -> categorical)?

Comment: I found this one works: `df2.x.replace(cat.codes, cat.__array__()).astype(cat.dtype)` (not very elegant though)

Comment: @orange: I don't know any nicer way than your way to map `codes` to `categories` :). My way would be use `dict` and `map` and my way doesn't look nicer than yours: `df2.y.map(dict(zip(cat.codes, cat.categories))).astype(cat.dtype)`. Another way is use `pd.cut` with specifying `bins` and `labels` option, but it looks worse.